# Did not get the Map Scroll End event in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-map

We are using the Map functionality with annotations.

Functionality:- We have 2000 records in the array but we need to filter  150 records according to the region changed in the Map in SwiftUI. But there is no scroll end event of the Map in SwiftUI.

We used the below code

```
 Map(coordinateRegion: self.$viewModel.region, interactionModes: [.all], annotationItems:  self.viewModel.mapLocations), annotationContent: { pin in

 }
```

We got the latest updated region in .onChange(of: viewModel.region) }. But we did not get the map scroll end event. We put the code in onChange(of) but it's lagging while scrolling. So, It's not worked for us.

Also. We tried Drag-Gesture but won't worked.

```
.gesture(DragGesture()
        .onEnded { value in
          //Did not getting this event while map scroll end
         })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI does not usually work as expected when trying to override gestures for built-in views especially with `Map`

`Combine` with `.debounce` is usually a better solution when it comes to filtering based on rapid changing `@Published` like a region